# How to get current URL of servletRequest.getRequestURI() using prettyfaces

Tags: jsf, servlets, prettyfaces

In my project using  PrimeFaces 5.1 with JSF 2.2 and PrettyFaces. If without use prettyfaces in web.xml to check log  servletRequest.getRequestURI() will return `/myproject/page/home.xhml`. 
But the same one added prettyfaces in web.xml  to check logger now it will print **/myproject/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js.xhtml,/myproject/javax.faces.resource/css/myProjectCSS/external.css.xhtml**

Why it will not print current URL

**web.xml**

```
<filter>
<filter-name>SessionPage</filter-name>
<filter-class>sample.SessionPage</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>SessionPage</filter-name>
<servlet-name>Custom Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter>
<filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name>
<filter-class>com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
<dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
<dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
<dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

**SessionPage**

```
.....
 @Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, 
            FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException
{
String contextPath = servletRequest.getRequestURI();
HttpSession session = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession(false);
HttpServletRequest servletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
HttpServletResponse servletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
system.out.println("Request URI: "+contextPath);
...
}
```

**home.xhtml**

```
<ui:composition ......>
<h:head>
 <h:outputStylesheet name="/resource/css/myProjectCSS/external.css"/>
....
</h:head>
...
</ui:composition>
```

**pretty.xml**

```
<url-mapping id="home">
<pattern value="/home"/>
<view-id value="/faces/pages/home.xhtml"/>
</url-mapping>

<url-mapping id="user">
<pattern value="/user"/>
<view-id value="/faces/pages/user.xhtml"/>
</url-mapping>
```

Then I need If use prettyfaces then I need requestURI to /**myproject/home** how to get it?

Comment: How do the urls for the spacer gif look like from the browser developer tool if you don't use prettyfaces? I would expect them to be the same so also matching **your** filter url pattern

Comment: In servlet class  I print requestURI  with use of prettyfaces system.out.println("Request URI: "+servletRequest.getRequestURI()); it will print  /myproject/javax.faces.resource/css/myProjectCSS/external.css.xhtml. Without using prettyfaces check to print it will show /myproject/pages/home.xthml

Comment: **that is not what I asked**

Comment: **Without use prettyfaces**  to check  browser developer  tool see **<link href="/myproject/faces/javax.faces.resource/css/myProjectCSS/external.cs‌​s.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">**. **With use of prettyfaces <link href="/myproject/javax.faces.resource/css/myProjectCSS/external.cs‌​s.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">**

Comment: The outgoing http requests for the spacer gif... not the content of the page

Comment: The http request for spacer gif without using prettyfaces http://localhost:8080/myproject/faces/spacer/clear.gif.xhtml.With use prettyfaces http://localhost:8080/myproject/spacer/clear.gif.xhtml .The difference is **faces** in both.